# Present perfect and simple past in same sentence "have" and "had"

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past

I have seen the other questions similar to this topic, but they all explain how the sentence is in present perfect and simple past. My question is, I would like to know why, or what the grammatical reason the use of both the words '**have**' and '**had**' is correct for the same subject ('it' is the subject here):

"**Not only did it *have* XYZ, it also *had* ABC.**"

Note, ABC and XYZ can be swapped and both ABC and XYZ hold true all the time eg, "not only did it have cruise control/automatic windows, it also had automatic windows/cruise control".

What are the grammatical rules allowing this? Note I am not saying it is breaking any rules, rather, I'm asking why don't we say "have" twice, or "had" twice.
Thanks

Comment: What so-called rule do you think it violates?

Comment: Can you please identify the present perfect tense in your example in bold? The PP for "it **had** X" is "*it **has had** X*"

Comment: The Q is based on incorrect parsing.

Comment: In the first clause the auxiliary verb (*did*) is inflected.  There is no auxiliary verb in the second, therefore the verb is inflected normally.

Comment: @Xanne I'm not saying it violates any rule, I am asking what are the grammar rules that means we have to use both have and had, rather than either word twice. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that was a typo, meant to put present perfect.

Comment: There is **no** present-tense form (neither normal present nor present perfect) in your sentence at all. “It did not [only] have” is just as much past tense as “it had”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see thanks. I'd still want to know why you can't use either word twice instead of both. For example, you would not say "Not only did it have chilli, it also have seafood." [and I cannot eat either etc etc].

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule that says you can't have the present tense and past tense in the same sentence.

In any case, your sentence contains no present tense verb. Both verbs are in the past tense. When the phrase *not only* introduces a clause it requires inversion of the subject and the verb as well as the addition of an auxiliary. It is the auxiliary which indicates the tense. The auxiliary here is *did*, which is the past tense.

The *Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p442) has this entry on *not only*:

> For emphasis, you can put *not only* first, followed by an auxiliary
>   or 'be', then the subject, then the main verb.
>
> - Not only did they send home substantial earnings, but they also saved money.
> - Not only do they go rarely go on school outings, they rarely, if ever, leave Brooklyn.